# conditional operator for operations?

Tags: c++

there is the conditional operator `x?a:b` , which often saves a lot of writing

now I found an expression like this

```
   if ( ( isMax && lower-higher <= distance) ||
        ( !isMax && lower-higher >= distance) ) { ...
```

where 
`isMax` is a bool defining if maximum (true) or minimum (false) is to be used, 
`lower` and `higher` are the boundaries (int in this case)

now i'm wondering: is there a way to somehow "pick" the operator this way?

I mean **not** the " x?a:b " way where the operand can be chosen, but to use a different operator

something like `bool (*op)() = isMax ? operator<=() :  operator >=`, used  on `lower-higher` ?

or like `lower-higher  (isMax? <= : >=) distance`, which won't work (of course)

Comment: what is the type of `isMax`?

Comment: Probably a `bool` looking at how it's used.

Comment: Would `<condition goes here>?( isMax && lower-higher <= distance):( !isMax && lower-higher >= distance)` work?

Comment: It has two separate evaluations, based on the boolean value of isMax, so 
isMax ? (lower-higher<=distance) : (lower-higher>=distance)  This doesn't really look any shorter. and trinary confuses more people than ||, so I'd just leave it be.

Comment: In response to your edit, if you want to pick the operator, that is often done with a template argument or a functor object. For example, look at std::priority_queue, which can be flipped from a max heap to a min heap by passing std::greater as its comparison argument, in the template. Or look at how std::sort takes a comparator.

Comment: This code has the ability to change from one mode to the other on a simple assignment. If it actually takes advantage of that, then I recommend the "strategy" design pattern with a functor object, so you can hot-swap it just as easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

But something close would be to write your own inline function with this effect:

```
template<class T>
inline bool compare(bool isLessThan, const T& left, const T& right)
{
    if (isLessThan) {
        return left <= right;
    }
    else {
        return left >= right;
    }
}

// ... later ...
if (compare(isMax, lower - higher, distance)) {
    // ...
}
```

My opinion (which you didn't ask for): just use an intermediate variable (or several if necessary)!

Comment: Consider making the comparison part of the type declaration, rather than an additional argument to the function. e.g. See the examples in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom `isMax` is a runtime value, so the choice of comparison operator cannot be determined at compile-time, which would be required for passing a functor.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing, but that's not really a problem if you instantiate the one you need. I suspect it will be fixed within some scope. If it changes back and forth, then this function or a functor object (as I was just mentioning in main comments -- strategy pattern) is better.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom, but a templated functor type cannot be instantiated with a run-time value as a template parameter.  The only way to use a functor, as far as I can imagine, would be to pass a parameter to its constructor which selects the comparison operator -- but this would turn the call into `compare(FuctorClass{isMax}, lower - higher, distance)`, which would be silly because it adds complexity without benefit.

Comment: @Arthur Tacca Since I have several calls to this comparison function (after "...later..." ) I think this is the best readable way to do it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ChristopherOicles I guess Kenny meant something like `auto compare=MyCompare{isMax}` followed by `if(compare(lower-higher, distance))`. If `isMax` is the same for several comparisons in a row then something like that would be a bit simpler than my answer.

Comment: @Arthur Tacca I guess that makes some sense, but internally the functor would still be doing what your `compare` functions does, except using a member variable rather than a function argument.  In any case, this was an X/Y problem: AndyG's answer satisfied OP's attempt at a solution, but I think your answer (without functors) was a more elegant solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you encapsulate the operators into functions with the same type:

```
namespace detail{
template<class T>
bool less_equal(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Using <=\n";
    return lhs <= rhs;
}

template<class T>
bool greater_equal(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Using >=\n";
    return lhs >= rhs;
}
}
```

And then we can write your logic as:

```
void DoTheThing(bool isMax, int lower, int higher, int distance)
{
    auto func = isMax ? &detail::less_equal<int> : &detail::greater_equal<int>;
    if (func(lower-higher, distance))
    {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

And a test:

```
int main()
{
    DoTheThing(true, 1, 1, 1); // <=
    DoTheThing(false, 1, 1, 1); // >=
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Using <=
Using >=
```

### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06ad848795189d3c)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the ternary conditional is of much help here. But you can save some typing (and perhaps even gain a bit of performance; profile it) by writing

`(2 * isMax - 1) * (lower - higher) <= distance`

This assums that `isMax` is a `bool` type, or is either 1 or 0. A perfect equivalent is the obtuse

`(2 * !!isMax - 1) * (lower - higher) <= distance`

On the grounds it took me 3 edits to get this correct, it might be encroaching on the borderline of readability.

Perhaps therefore leave it as it is, or bury the complexity in a function.

Comment: thanks for trying, and i understand what you're doing, but that's not answering my question :)

Comment: operator+(1); for "bury the complexity"; it should be named and stored.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [this is possible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/058485f9b831ed82)<sup>1</sup>:

```
(x ? [](int a, int b){ return a >= b; } : [](int a, int b){ return a <= b; })(a, b)
```

Should you do that, though? I'd personally just go with a `(bool, int, int)` function.

<sup>1</sup> I was a bit surprised at first, but I guess it's triggering the lambda decay somehow. If they were closures (had something within `[]`) they would be different types and as such the type of the `?:` would depend on runtime state.